# Safari SVG Linear Gradient does not work in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

Can someone tell me why the linear gradient on the svg element in the header and footer wont work in Safari on this [site](http://emtre.ch.tajo.host.ch/aktuell/)? One possible solution i've found on the internet, was wrapping the gradient with a `<defs>` tag which did not help in this case.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Safari doesn't like the `<base>` tag. It stops the fill from working on that browser, so you get the default fill which is black.

e.g.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<base href="http://emtre.ch.tajo.host.ch/" />
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="footer-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2000, 1200">

    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#efefef;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFF;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0,595 1903,0 1903,1010 0,1010" fill="url(#grad1)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

against

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="footer-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2000, 1200">

    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#efefef;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFF;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0,595 1903,0 1903,1010 0,1010" fill="url(#grad1)"></polygon>
</svg>
```